# Need to create NTFS partition on my hard drive but mount point "/" is stopping me

Tags: partitioning, windows, gparted, mountpoint

Okay, I'm not very good with computers. I got ubuntu a few weeks ago, after having windows which was becoming rubbish so I deleted it. Since then, I've found it hard to get around using some programs without windows, and I'm not a big fan of wine. Got the bootable dvd for windows but when installing it, it says I can't as I don't have a partition with NTFS formatting. Followed this thread https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition/CreatingPartitions but was unsuccessful, because in this thread they used an unformatted hard drive. Tried to unmount mine, but can't because the mount point has an "/" there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to create a partition on the drive referred to as '/'?

Comment: Yes, yes i am! Is it possible?

Comment: Basically no, not the way you are trying to do it.  You would need to create a bootable USB (Referred to often as a 'live CD'), boot from that and run gparted there.  You should shrink your existing partition to create unused space, which your windows disk can then use for installation.  Alro, prior to doing any of this read through [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you cannot unmount the root partition while you are using it. You will have to shut down your system and boot from another media like a USB stick or a CD and get into live mode to modify partitions on your HDD.

From my experience the best solution for this kind of problem - if you need to run some Windows program alongside Linux - is to use a virtual machine and Windows install there . **It is much safer and easier**.

Here, I suggest you to install [Oracle VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads). It's a well known multi-platform Virtual Machine program.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick response! Okay, that is helpful. Would i be able to create a new partition on the root partition while it is still mounted, and then format that to NTFS? Basically, when i go to install windows manually, it comes up with a list of two partitions, both of which windows cannot start on.

Comment: Actually, you cannot see Linux partitions during Windows installation as Windows supports only NTFS filesystem. You could create a new partition like @Bryan said. Get into Ubuntu Live mode, open up Terminal, type `gparted` (if the command displayed any error then type `sudo gparted`). Then, you will be seeing a gparted application on the screen. There, you could create or modify partitions. If you have any difficulty on how to do, you could refer this link. http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual.

Comment: No problem. But I think that you lack some terminology or it is me - because I cannot quite understand you. If you are not very good at computers (as you say) I would suggest you to install and run the VirtualBox machine.

If you really want to install the Windows on HDD you have to create new partition for it by resizing the last partition on HDD and format that partition to NTFS. After that you can install Windows there. But be aware! After that you can **no longer boot Ubuntu** - you will have to [recover GRUB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows).

Answer (score 0):

Use Gparted from live CD and then

- Unmount as u were saying becoz u cannot unmount the disk from which you are using currently so you have unmount from Gparted bootable pendrive
- or you change the partition as you want.
- *Kindly notify me if you face any more problem*